# Why does this javac command not work?

Tags: java, linux

```
javac -cp .:gson-2.3.1.jar:commons-io-2.4.jar File.java
```

The above command works on one of my linux machines. However it does not work on another one even though it is the same distro! (Debian)

The shell does not throw any errors of any sort which suggests it is finding the .jar files just fine, however the java compiler throws errors wherever I have used the .jar files in my code e.g. "the import org.apache cannot be resolved" , "the import org.gson cannot be resolved" etc.

The Java file and both the required .jar files are in the current directory. I am using Java 1.6. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you check any other Java commands working on that machine?

Comment: Yes, other java programs without 3rd party libs in the compile path work on that machine

Comment: Maybe the jar files are corrupt. Check with `md5sum gson-2.3.1.jar` and compare output with other machines that work.

Comment: Just tried that. Check sums are the same

Comment: Cupawn, import java.util.Nonsense says the import cannot be resolved surprisingly :) Just like it says the import org.apache cannot be resolved. Also I think you are right in saying that javac ignores packages it cant find. Entered in a rubbish name and it still didn't throw any file not found errors

Comment: alias points to /usr/bin/javac so I don't think theres much off there. Tried typing from scratch still doesn't work

Comment: I see, any other ideas??

Comment: Looks like the problem was with -cp. See my posted answer

Comment: What does java -version say? This is very hard to believe.

Comment: java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.13) (6b18-1.8.13-0+squeeze1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)

Comment: @bmargulies I see `classpath` and no mention of `cp` in http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/sun/tools/javac/Main.java (same for OpenJDK 8 as well) so seems valid. @noobcoder is there a different (non-OpenJDK) compiler on the systems where `-cp` works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIXED. Out of desperation I changed `javac -cp` to `javac -classpath` and it magically worked. Always pays to be explicit!